# A mistake in the tour page under "Dont ask about"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was reading the tour page for this website and stumbled across a minor mistake under the *Don't ask about* heading:

[image]

In the third bullet point, you can see:

> Questions with too many possible answers, or *answers* that would require an extremely long answer

I believe the highlighted *answers* must be changed to **questions** to make that point meaningful.

Comment: Nice pickup and thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 1):

I've reset this to the default text:

> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

This is how the text reads on most of the other sites around the network.

Thanks for letting us know.